# Laravel Passport with custom guard is not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-passport

I want to implement multi-type user authentication with Laravel and Passport. There are users and admins with different tables and different models.
In the `auth.php` config, I've added the guards and providers:

```
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'admins',
        'hash' => false
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => User::class,
    ],
    'admins' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

I'm going to log in with a user in the `AuthController` and create a token for the user:

```
 $token = $user->createToken('user'.$user->id)->accessToken;
```

Now, I have a route that is just for admins, and users shouldn't be allowed to get in, I prefer to handle this by middleware:

```
 Route::post('/check', function () {
     if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
         dd(Auth::guard('admin')->user());
      }
 })->middleware('auth:admin');
```

Here is my question, **This middleware is not working** and the user can get in, but when I want to print the authenticated user I get an admin who has the same **ID** as the authenticated user. But if there is no admin with that ID I'll get the **401** error.
How can solve this problem?